# Passport Authenticator complains of that 'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type

Tags: typescript, passport.js

I'm trying to type a function to accept both local and general passport authenticator. Unfortunately I'm getting a "this" Typescript error:

```
import { Passport, Authenticator } from 'passport';

const alternativePassport: Authenticator = new Passport();
```

Causes the error:

```sh
Type 'import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/passport/index").Authenticator<import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/express/index").Handler, any, any, import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/passport/index").AuthenticateOptions>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/passport/index").PassportStatic.Authenticator<import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/express/index").Handler, any, any, import("/home/max/workspace/npm/graphql-passport/node_modules/@types/passport/index").Authenticate...'.
  The types returned by 'use(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Authenticator<Handler, any, any, AuthenticateOptions>' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Authenticator<Handler, any, any, AuthenticateOptions>'.ts(2322)
const alternativePassport: Authenticator<express.Handler, any, any, passport.AuthenticateOptions>
No quick fixes available
```

*Minor note:* In the real code I want to pass the alternativePassport into a function with an optional passport object that is assigned to the passport.default export if object isn't provided.

Comment: There seems to be some weir typing on the default generic `Authenticator` interface... It should be enough to remove the `Authenticator` type annotation and let typescript figure out the type itself. I think what the compiler is trying to tell you, is that `Passport` may not match exactly what is set for the default generic parameters in `Authenticator`

Comment: @AramBecker - not really, I want to write a function that takes an `Authenticator` and thus I need to know the type that I'm suppose to use.

Comment: It should still be the same problem. `Authenticator` is generic and the default types for it don't match Passport. You could try a generic function (`function foo<A extends Authenticator>(passport: A) {...}`) to automatically match the generic parameters to your variable

Comment: If that is not enough you may have to infer the parameters

Comment: Yep, you are right, nothing seems to get around this error. The generic type by `passport` Does not seem very well constructed or is just too complicated for `ts` to resolve correctly. Only option I'd see is to open an issue or specifically ignore this error every time. The alternative is to rebuild the `Authenticator` type yourself which might be the cleanest option until the issue is fixed by `passport`

Comment: @AramBecker - great, if it is an issue with the passport type declarations I will post an issue. As long as I haven't missed anything crucial regarding how to use the types I'm happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with either the typings of `Passport` or some underlying issue with `Authenticator`. To be honest, I'm not sure what *TS* is complaining about, when I redefine the type exactly as it was before, just re-declaring `use` and `unuse` the error goes away. My only guess is that `passport` overlays the `Authenticator` interface somewhere or there is a typescript bug:

```js
interface WorkingAuthenticator<
  InitializeRet = express.Handler,
  AuthenticateRet = any,
  AuthorizeRet = AuthenticateRet,
  AuthorizeOptions = AuthenticateOptions
> extends Omit<Authenticator<InitializeRet, AuthenticateRet, AuthorizeRet, AuthorizeOptions>,  'use' | 'unuse'> {
  // This is exactly the same as the `Authenticator` interface
  use(strategy: Strategy): this;
  use(name: string, strategy: Strategy): this;
}

const auth: WorkingAuthenticator = new Passport();
```

An issue on the `passport` Github page is probably the way to go here, you can use the `WorkingAuthernticator` type until the issue is fixed or maybe somebody working on `passport` knows why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import passport, { Passport } from 'passport'

const alternativePassport: passport.Authenticator = new Passport()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?